# Please explain the code?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
  int N, K, i, j, k, x, final, cur, A[22];

  for(i=!!scanf("%d %d",&N,&K), printf("%d\n",(final=N*N)-N);i<=N;A[i++]=i);
  for(i=(cur=N)-1; i>=1; i--)
    for(j=1; j<=i; printf("%d %d min\n%d %d max\n",A[j],A[j+1],A[j],A[j+1]),A[j]=++cur, A[j+1]=++cur, j++);
     for(printf("%d",final-1+(cur=final)*0+(x=2)*0); cur>N; printf(" %d",cur), cur-=x, x+=2);
  return 0;
}
```

Please explain the use of 2 exclamation marks in the first "for" statement.

Comment: Do you know what a single exclamation mark means in C? (Rhetorical question. If you don't, you should read up on your basic C.) Now apply that twice!!

Comment: a single exclamation "!" means taking a logical NOT, so applying . So it's value will be 0 or 1. Depending upon value of return of scanf. Do `man scanf` to find out more about it. When it returns success/failure that should tell what two !! mean.

Comment: The code need to be formatted it is not at all readable.I will do it for now,but pls remember it afterwards.

Comment: 'Please dig a latrine ditch' - why would I want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just explain first for loops, last 3 for loops is easy to understand.
Step by step explanation.

**Step 1:**

```
for(i=!!scanf("%d %d",&N,&K), printf("%d\n",(final=N*N)-N);i<=N;A[i++]=i);
```

Here, `scanf("%d %d",&N,&K)` returns 2 (number of integer read successfully.)

**Step 2:** single negation, `!2 = 0`, now negate this 0, `!0 = 1`. So, `i = !!2 = 1`

**Step 3:** Suppose your input was `3 5` [N=3, K=5]. so output of `printf("%d\n",(final=N*N)-N)` will be `final = (3*3)-3 = 6`

**Step 4:** Checking condition: `i<=N` means, is 1<=N? If yes then this loop continues until the condition becomes false. in the process as `A[i++] = i`, first the index i of A is set then i increases by 1, then the value of A[i] is set to i. So finally you get the following array:

```
A[1] = 2;
A[2] = 3;
A[3] = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 3: Suppose your input was `3 5 [N=3, K=5]`. so output of `printf("%d\n",(final=N*N)-N)` will be `(final = (3*3)-3) = 6(output) ,final =6`.